# How To Find Direction of Normal Contact Force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, free-body-diagram, string

I am a little bit confused. while doing questions I can see direction of normal forces are different. In Some Cases, It is perpendicular to the contact surface and towards the object on which normal is applied. In Other Cases, I can see it is perpendicular  but opposite direction...

[image: Case 1]

In The Above Image If You Draw The FBD of man you can see the direction of normal is different from the below image if we draw the fbd of B.

[image: Case 2]

Then How will i determine the direction of normal force upwards or downwards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal force acts at right angles to surface.

When considering the direction of a normal force one should consider what would happen if it is not there.

For your second example here are the FBDs with the coloured forces  (other than black) being Newton third law pairs.

[image]

For block $B$ if the normal force due to $A$ was not there block $B$ would accelerate downwards due to the gravitational force on it.
This means that the normal force on $B$ due to $A$ must be upwards and hence (N3L) the normal force on $A$ due to $B$ must be upwards.

*In The Above Image If You Draw The FBD of man you can see the direction of normal is different from the below image if we draw the fbd of B.*
I do not agree with this statement.

Your first example is slightly more complicated and depends on whether or not the person is *anchored* to the platform.

If the person is not anchored then the only direction possible for the normal force on the person due to the platform is upwards and hence (N3L) the normal force on the platform due to the person is downwards.
So the normal force on the person is in the same direction as that on block $B$ due to block $A$.

If the person is not anchored to the platform then, without any further information, the direction of the normal force on the person due to the platform is indeterminate so you could put either up or down but then making sure that the direction of the normal force on the platform due to the person is shown to be in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer. I understood but as you said in the last paragraph... is this possible in this question [Link Of Question](https://leibniz-math.org/JEE/books/physics/Concepts%20of%20Physics%20Volume%201/Concepts%20of%20Physics%20Volume%201%20-%20Chapter%205%20-%20%20NEWTON-S%20LAWS%20OF%20MOTION/) Page  82 Q 39

Comment: And Please See The Last Two Paragraphs They Have The Same Condition If the Person is not anchored. What will happen if it is anchored

Comment: Think of the person's shoes being stuck to the platform, then the platform can either push the person up or pull the person down.

Comment: This is a "standard" Mechanics problem and you might find [link 1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/pages/week-2-newtons-laws/ps-2-3-window-washer-problem/) and [link 2](http://physics.wm.edu/Courses/Phys101/Tests/test1_3.html) of interest?

Answer (score 1):

The direction of the normal force can be determined by looking at Newton third law and some logic.

**Example:**
Imagine this roller coaster here. As you get to the top of the loop, what is stopping you from pushing through the tracks? It's the normal force. The normal force is what keeps things together in a sense, and ensures that things don't just fall through.

[image: roller coaster]

**Another way/example of thinking about it:**
Imagine you are pushing up on a table from underneath, why doesn't your hands just displace the atoms and just push through? It's because a normal force acts.

Comment: thanks i understood your examples but can you please tell the same logic while drawing the fbd of man in image 1?

Comment: @PiyushBaweja the FBD for man in one would be a normal force upwards for his legs, then the normal force on the rope is 0 (if I understand the rope is just sideways with no force on it).

Comment: rope is having some tension and the same direction i marked for the man you said but in actual it is in downward direction... that's creating confusion

Comment: @PiyushBaweja yes but that tension is not a normal force on the man.

Comment: just see above edited comment

Comment: The normal force would still be downward. It may be canceled out but is still downward. Isolate just the man. What are the forces? Some gravitational force in the -y direction, in the +y there is tension and normal force. That normal force could be close to 0 but we do not know. Does this make sense?

Comment: but the question remains the same if we just see how we can know ki what direction it will it can be normal and tension +y direction and -y direction gravitation or tension +y direction and gravitation force and normal -y dir